# Expectation Maximization Algorithm (EM) for Gaussian Mixture Models (GMMs)

Tags: machine-learning, python, algorithms, unsupervised-learning, numpy

I'm trying to apply the Expectation Maximization algorithm (EM) to a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) using Python and NumPy. The PDF document I am basing my implementation on can be found [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Esmyth/courses/cs274/notes/EMnotes.pdf).
Below are the equations:

$\mathrm{E}-\text{step:}$

$$w_{ik} = \frac{\pi_k \cdot p_k(x_i|z_k, \mu_k, \Sigma_k)}{\sum_{m=1}^{K} \pi_m \cdot p_m(x_i|z_m, \mu_m, \Sigma_m)}, \; [1]$$

$\text{where:}$

$${\displaystyle (2\pi )^{-{1}}|{\Sigma_k}|^{-{\frac {1}{2}}}\,\mathrm e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}(x_i -{\mu_k})^{\!{\mathsf {T}}}{{\Sigma_k }}^{-1}(x_i -{\mu_k})}.} 
$$

$\mathrm{M}-\text{step:}$

$$\pi_k^{\text{new}} = \frac{N_k}{N}, \; [2]$$

$\text{where:}$

$$N_k = \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_{ik}.$$

$$\mu_k^{\text{new}} = \frac{1}{N_k} \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_{ik} \cdot x_i, \; [3]$$

$$\Sigma_k^{\text{new}} = \frac{1}{N_k} \sum_{i=1}^N w_{ik} (x_i - \mu_k)(x_i - \mu_k)^\mathsf {T}. \; [4]$$
When applying the algorithm I get the mean of the first and second cluster equal to:

```
array([[2.50832195],
       [2.51546208]])
```

When the actual vector means for the first and second cluster are, respectively:

```
array([[0],
       [0]])
```

and:

```
array([[5],
       [5]])
```

The same thing happens when getting the values of the covariance matrices I get:

```
array([[7.05168736, 6.17098629],
       [6.17098629, 7.23009494]])
```

When it should be:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

for both clusters.
Here is the code:

```
np.random.seed(1)

# first cluster
X_11 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
X_21 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)

# second cluster
X_12 = np.random.normal(5, 1, 1000)
X_22 = np.random.normal(5, 1, 1000)

X_1 = np.concatenate((X_11,X_12), axis=None)
X_2 = np.concatenate((X_21,X_22), axis=None)

# data matrix of k x n dimensions (2 x 2000 dimensions)
X = np.concatenate((np.array([X_1]),np.array([X_2])), axis=0)

# multivariate normal distribution function gives n x 1 vector (2000 x 1 vector)
def normal_distribution(x, mu, sigma):
  mvnd = []
  for i in range(np.shape(x)[1]):
    gd = (2*np.pi)**(-2/2) * np.linalg.det(sigma)**(-1/2) * np.exp((-1/2) * np.dot(np.dot((x[:,i:i+1]-mu).T, np.linalg.inv(sigma)), (x[:,i:i+1]-mu)))
    mvnd.append(gd)
  return np.reshape(np.array(mvnd), (np.shape(x)[1], 1))

# Initialized parameters
sigma_1 = np.array([[10, 0],
                    [0, 10]])
sigma_2 = np.array([[10, 0],
                    [0, 10]])
mu_1 = np.array([[10], 
                 [10]])
mu_2 = np.array([[10], 
                 [10]])
pi_1 = 0.5
pi_2 = 0.5

Sigma_1 = np.empty([2000, 2, 2])
Sigma_2 = np.empty([2000, 2, 2])

for i in range(10):
  # E-step:
  w_i1 = (pi_1*normal_distribution(X, mu_1, sigma_1))/(pi_1*normal_distribution(X, mu_1, sigma_1) + pi_2*normal_distribution(X, mu_2, sigma_2))
  w_i2 = (pi_2*normal_distribution(X, mu_2, sigma_2))/(pi_1*normal_distribution(X, mu_1, sigma_1) + pi_2*normal_distribution(X, mu_2, sigma_2))
  # M-step:
  pi_1 = np.sum(w_i1)/2000
  pi_2 = np.sum(w_i2)/2000
  mu_1 = np.array([(1/(np.sum(w_i1)))*np.sum(w_i1.T*X, axis=1)]).T
  mu_2 = np.array([(1/(np.sum(w_i2)))*np.sum(w_i2.T*X, axis=1)]).T
  for i in range(2000):
    Sigma_1[i:i+1, :, :] = w_i1[i:i+1,:]*np.dot((X[:,i:i+1]-mu_1), (X[:,i:i+1]-mu_1).T)
    Sigma_2[i:i+1, :, :] = w_i2[i:i+1,:]*np.dot((X[:,i:i+1]-mu_2), (X[:,i:i+1]-mu_2).T)
    sigma_1 = (1/(np.sum(w_i1)))*np.sum(Sigma_1, axis=0)
    sigma_2 = (1/(np.sum(w_i2)))*np.sum(Sigma_2, axis=0)
```

Would really appreciate if someone could point out the mistake in my code or in my misunderstanding of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason why you aren't getting fitted values close to the true values could be the initial values of the parameters used.

It's likely what you have found is a **local maxima**. You have to try a number of initial starts and then pick the one with that gives the highest likelihood.

Comment: You are absolutely right. When I use different initial values I get the right means and covariances of the sampled clusters.